# Iphone TabBar Application

Tags: iphone

I start to develop app in tab bar application template..

Here my first page is login page after loagin it go to home page and all navigation will happen..

Here i don't want tab bar only in login page.How to doo this?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

on the first tab, add whatever check you need for whether or not they are logged in, and if not, present a modal view with the login fields.

```
//some test here to determine state of self.registered
if(self.registered==FALSE){
            LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"loginView" bundle: nil];
            login.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
            [login release];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you can hide and how uitabbarcontroller -

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }

    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];





}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
        }


    }

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**In delegate.h declare your views,**

```
UIView *indicatorView; 
UIImageView *splashV;
```

**now in delegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
         indicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
     splashV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
     [splashV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
     [indicatorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [indicatorView addSubview:splashV];
    [self.window addSubview:indicatorView];

}
```

& **on successful login**

```
-(void)SuccessfulLoginDone
{
    [window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Hope that would be much better to do this task.